# twitter bootstrap - dropdown items in navbar not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Asp.NET with twitter bootstrap. I used NuGet to reference Bootstrap. 
I have a sample page wherein I am using the following code

```
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My website</a>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a id="A1" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a id="A2" runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                  <li><a id="A3" runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Accounts<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
```

but whenever I am clicking the Accounts dropdown navigation bar the popup is not appearing. its not doing anything in fact.

All the other styles seem to work fine. for example the navigation bar is rendered properly and the footer- well is working fine as well .

**EDIT**

I am referencing the Jquery and the bootstrap.js in the head section of my master page.

and here is the entire code : [Entire Code](http://pastebin.com/8i4tzEtQ)

Thanks

Comment: Have you declare the bootstrap.js in your page ?

Comment: and is it the correct version? Make sure the Bootstrap JS file you include is the same as the bootstrap docs you're using.

Comment: @Pascalz - yes i have done that already

Comment: @bzupnick - I think NuGet will already handle that .. won't it ?

Comment: And Bootstrap.js need jquery declared before

Comment: @Pascalz - yes .. i have it in the same order.

Comment: try to reference your jquery/bootstrap js file at bottom just before </body>

Comment: @Pascalz did that , still not working.. btw. i have posted the entire page markup on pastebin.. here is the link : http://pastebin.com/8i4tzEtQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your all help guys, but I managed to resolve it .. I had not added the reference to the script popover.js . I downloaded the script from the bootstrap site and now its working like charm .. thanks once again !